what is the behaviour of the orderBy clause when used in an aggregate over a window function
I'm trying to run some aggregate some string fields in a spark dataframe using the collect_set() as aggregator over a Window but I'm failing to understand the behaviour when using the orderBy clause (the intent is to control the order of elemnts in the set):
val data = Seq(("opp1","y","p1"),("opp1","y","p2"),("opp1","n","p3"),("opp2","y","p1"),("opp2","y","p4"),("opp2","n","p5"),("opp2","n","p6"),("opp2","n","p7"))

val df = data.toDF("opp", "stock", "product")

import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

df.withColumn("product_stock_status", collect_set(col("product")).over(Window.partitionBy(col("opp"), col("stock")))).show()
+----+-----+-------+--------------------+
| opp|stock|product|product_stock_status|
+----+-----+-------+--------------------+
|opp2|    n|     p5|        [p6, p5, p7]|
|opp2|    n|     p6|        [p6, p5, p7]|
|opp2|    n|     p7|        [p6, p5, p7]|
|opp1|    n|     p3|                [p3]|
|opp1|    y|     p1|            [p1, p2]|
|opp1|    y|     p2|            [p1, p2]|
|opp2|    y|     p1|            [p4, p1]|
|opp2|    y|     p4|            [p4, p1]|
+----+-----+-------+--------------------+

df.withColumn("product_stock_status", collect_set(col("product")).over(Window.partitionBy(col("opp"), col("stock")).orderBy(col("product").asc))).show()
+----+-----+-------+--------------------+
| opp|stock|product|product_stock_status|
+----+-----+-------+--------------------+
|opp2|    n|     p5|                [p5]|
|opp2|    n|     p6|            [p6, p5]|
|opp2|    n|     p7|        [p6, p5, p7]|
|opp1|    n|     p3|                [p3]|
|opp1|    y|     p1|                [p1]|
|opp1|    y|     p2|            [p1, p2]|
|opp2|    y|     p1|                [p1]|
|opp2|    y|     p4|            [p4, p1]|
+----+-----+-------+--------------------+

df.withColumn("product_stock_status", collect_set(col("product")).over(Window.partitionBy(col("opp"), col("stock")).orderBy(col("product").desc))).show()
+----+-----+-------+--------------------+
| opp|stock|product|product_stock_status|
+----+-----+-------+--------------------+
|opp2|    n|     p7|                [p7]|
|opp2|    n|     p6|            [p6, p7]|
|opp2|    n|     p5|        [p6, p5, p7]|
|opp1|    n|     p3|                [p3]|
|opp1|    y|     p2|                [p2]|
|opp1|    y|     p1|            [p1, p2]|
|opp2|    y|     p4|                [p4]|
|opp2|    y|     p1|            [p4, p1]|
+----+-----+-------+--------------------+

The behaviour I'm looking for is the one if the first aggregation, the one that does not contain the orderBy clause but this means having no control over the order in the set.
As soon as I use the orderBy clause it stops making sense to me in other words I do not understand why it is building these sequential aggregates.
Running Spark 2.4.
Thank you!

a set is unordered

@yurib - fair point, thank you, not strictly relevant to the focus of my question which was concerning what I have since learned, thar a growing window is the default when orderBy on it's own is used (resulting in that incremental set)

OK, so reading the docs and previously asked on SO definitely helps:

When ordering is not defined, an unbounded window frame (rowFrame,
unboundedPreceding,  *       unboundedFollowing) is used by default.
When ordering is defined, a growing window frame  *       (rangeFrame,
unboundedPreceding, currentRow) is used by default.

So the key is the growing window frame which is the default when ordering is defined. Adding a rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing) removes the growing window frame and aggregates over the entire partition per the partitioning defined.
df.withColumn("product_stock_status", collect_set(col("product")).over(Window.partitionBy(col("opp"), col("stock")).orderBy(col("product").desc).rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFo
llowing))).show()
+----+-----+-------+--------------------+
| opp|stock|product|product_stock_status|
+----+-----+-------+--------------------+
|opp2|    n|     p7|        [p6, p5, p7]|
|opp2|    n|     p6|        [p6, p5, p7]|
|opp2|    n|     p5|        [p6, p5, p7]|
|opp1|    n|     p3|                [p3]|
|opp1|    y|     p2|            [p1, p2]|
|opp1|    y|     p1|            [p1, p2]|
|opp2|    y|     p4|            [p4, p1]|
|opp2|    y|     p1|            [p4, p1]|
+----+-----+-------+--------------------+


It's a difficult area that I also had to get used to. Good that you asked, I was to answer tonight, but good on you. +1
